# Tentei depurar por um longo tempo, mas não consigo omitir corretamente caracteres repetidos consecutivos

Tags: c, falha-de-segmentação

Estou tentando criar código para omitir caracteres repetidos consecutivos. Não sei o que está acontecendo e tentei depurar por horas. De qualquer forma, estou tentando localizar ocorrências de caracteres repetidos consecutivos e depois contar mais. Meu código é uma merda. Como posso corrigir isso?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char Str[] = "gggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggghggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg";
    unsigned long Len = strlen(Str);
    /*for (unsigned long Pos = 0; Str[Pos]; Pos++) {
        if (Str[Pos] >= 'A' && Str[Pos] <= 'Z') {
            Str[Pos] += 'a'-'A';
        } else if (Str[Pos] < 0) {
            Str[Pos] = '_';
            Len++;
        } else {
            switch (Str[Pos]) {
                case '@':
                    Str[Pos] = 'a';
                    break;
                case '8':
                    Str[Pos] = 'b';
                    break;
                case '(':
                    Str[Pos] = 'c';
                    break;
                case '3':
                    Str[Pos] = 'e';
                    break;
                case '#':
                    Str[Pos] = 'h';
                    break;
                case '1':
                case '!':
                    Str[Pos] = 'i';
                    break;
                case '&':
                    Str[Pos] = 'k';
                    break;
                case '0':
                    Str[Pos] = 'o';
                    break;
                case '?':
                    Str[Pos] = 'p';
                    break;
                case '5':
                case '$':
                    Str[Pos] = 's';
                    break;
                case '7':
                case '+':
                    Str[Pos] = 't';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }*/ //Não é relevante
    char PrevChar = *Str;
    unsigned long Pos = 1;
    while (Pos < Len) {
        register unsigned long RChars = 0;
        for (; Str[Pos+RChars] == PrevChar; RChars++);
        if (RChars) {
            memmove(Str+Pos, Str+Pos+RChars, (Len-=(RChars))-Pos);
        }
        if (!Str[RChars+Pos]) {
            break;
        }
        PrevChar = Str[Pos];
        Pos++;
    }
    Str[Pos] = '\0';

    puts(Str);
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado:

```
Terminated due to signal: SEGMENTATION FAULT (11)
264, 401, 666
s18446744073709551479, 399, 265
```

Vejo quanto tempo tento resolver meu problema e consegui colocar a cabeça na mesa, no chão e na parede embaixo de mim, porque me faz querer chorar.

Answer (score 0):

Reescrevi o seu programa assim:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void elimina_seguidos_repetidos(char *dst, const char *src) {
    char ultimo = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (1) {
        char c = src[i];
        if (!c) break;
        if (c != ultimo) {
            dst[j] = c;
            j++;
            ultimo = c;
        }
        i++;
    }
    dst[j] = 0;
}

int main(void) {
    char *entrada = "ggggggghgggg";
    char novo[sizeof(entrada)];
    printf("Entrada: %s\n", entrada, novo);
    elimina_seguidos_repetidos(novo, entrada);
    printf("Entrada: %s Novo: %s\n", entrada, novo);
    char entrada2[50];
    strcpy(entrada2, "aaaaabaaaabaaabbbcaa");
    printf("Antes: %s\n", entrada2);
    elimina_seguidos_repetidos(entrada2, entrada2);
    printf("Depois: %s\n", entrada2);
    return 0;
}
```

A ideia é que a função `elimina_seguidos_repetidos` funcione com dois parâmetros, sendo eles respectivamente a string de destino e a de origem, da mesma forma que fazem as funções `strcpy` e `strcat`. Ele também funciona se as duas strings forem uma só, modificando então a string dada.

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](https://ideone.com/Jlt30L)

Um erro que o seu código original tinha é o de tentar modificar strings cridas pelo compilador (tal como aquela `"gggggg ... "`). Essas strings tem proteção de memória contra escrita. Tentar modificá-las causará uma falha de segmentação. É por isso que no código acima eu escrevo apenas nas variáveis `novo` e `entrada2`, mas nunca em `entrada` que é a constante string `"ggggggghgggg"`. Já a string `"aaaaabaaaabaaabbbcaa"` é copiada por meio de `strcpy` para `entrada2`, de forma que ela também nunca será alterada.

Para demonstrar esse problema, veja esse código aqui:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *foo = "abcdefg";
    foo[1] = 'x';
    printf("%s", foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Ele tenta mudar a string constante `"abcdefg"`, e por isso dá um erro. [Veja esse daí dando erro no ideone.](https://ideone.com/rbT9ETO)

Comment: obrigado!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Asadefa Se esta resposta resolveu seu problema e não lhe resta mais nenhuma dúvida, clique no "✔️" que está à esquerda da resposta para marcá-la como aceita/correta, o que também marca a sua pergunta como solucionada/respondida. Caso contrário, sinta-se livre para comentar.